# Pass multiple values to query dynamically in java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am trying to pass multiple values in a SELECT QUERY consisting of two IN clauses. I would like to execute the following query:

```
String sql = "select ADDRESS from CDR where APARTY in(?,?,?) intersect select ADDRESS from CDR where BPARTY in (?,?) and USAGETYPE='SMSMT'";
```

How can I pass value using `preparedStatement.setString()` ?.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To build your query you can use for example `StringBuilder` for example :

Consider you have a two lists like this :

```
List<String> values1 = new ArrayList<>();
values1.add("val1_1");
values1.add("val1_2");
values1.add("val1_3");
List<String> values2 = new ArrayList<>();
values2.add("val2_1");
values2.add("val2_2");
```

Now we will build the query :

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("select ADDRESS from CDR where APARTY IN(");

for (int i = 0; i < values1.size(); i++) {
    sql.append(i == values1.size() - 1 ? "?" : "?,");
}
sql.append(") intersect select ADDRESS from CDR where BPARTY IN (");
for (int i = 0; i < values2.size(); i++) {
    sql.append(i == values2.size() - 1 ? "?" : "?,");
}
sql.append(") and USAGETYPE='SMSMT'");
System.out.println(sql);
```

Until now this can gives you :

```
select ADDRESS from CDR where APARTY IN(?,?,?) intersect select ADDRESS from CDR where BPARTY IN (?,?) and USAGETYPE='SMSMT'
```

Now you have to use this query in the PreparedStatement :

```
try (PreparedStatement pstm = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    int i = 1;
    for (String s : values1) {
        pstm.setString(i++, s);
    }

    for (String s : values2) {
        pstm.setString(i++, s);
    }
    //...execute the statement and retrieve the results 
}
```

Comment: Very good solution as it prevents SQL injection. It relies indeed on `PreparedStatement.setString()` for each String value added in the `IN` clause. As a side node, I think that the iterations with `i` and `j` you are using are a little bit complicated and could be simpler. Personally, I would have use a single `int` and an `enhanced for` to iterate on each list.

Comment: thank you @davidxxx i appreciate it i already do do it with your suggest what did you think?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it :

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = yourconnexiontoDB.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, "your first string");
pstmt.setString(2, "your second string");
```

etc ... for the rest of the values.